# Two rows should not have the same values

Tags: mysql

I have a table which looks like this

```
+------+-----------+-----------+
| name |   likes   |   date    |
+------+-----------+-----------+
| John | choclates | 31/3/2016 |
| John | cake      | 31/3/2016 |
| Jack | choclates | 31/3/2016 |
| Jack | pie       | 31/3/2016 |
+------+-----------+-----------+
```

I don't want the data in the 'likes' column for a particular name to repeat.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should have defined a `unique key` on `(name, likes)`